# Code analysis for PyQt4

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt, code-analysis

Is there a tool to analyze my code project in PyQt4 and draw it if possible? I use Python with Qt4 in the Eclipse SDK.

Comment: "Draw it"?  Draw *what*, specifically?

Comment: @Ira Baxter :  flowchart for the code

Comment: @s.jor.ibra: You should edit your question to make that "flowchart" part clear.  I'm not sure how useful a flowchart would be; Python only has structured control flow so you practically see the "flowchart" in the indentation (one of the points of Python block-style-with-indents).  You might be more interested in a *call* graph, but Python is pretty dynamic and building an accurate call graph is likely pretty hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at python parser of [SourceAnalyzer tools + QSAGUI](https://bitbucket.org/sourceanalyzer/sourceanalyzer-workflow) . Actually this isn't a stable version for python parser (may be just alpha version), but it can get some call-graph from your code and visualize it with dot language (Graphviz). Also we are open for your feedback and hot fixes.